# C++ vector: should I copy or swap?

Tags: c++, copy, swap, stdvector

I have a class  that has a vector member variable, which I fill up as follows:

```
class Foo {
vector<int> v;
void g() {
  vector<int> w;
  // fill w
  v = w;
}

};
```

My question: the temporary vector w can grow to be huge and I don't want to pay the price
of copy construction. Should I be using std::swap instead of copy here? My understanding
is that std::swap will be more efficient due to specialization for vector (where it
will just swap pointers to the heap).

Comment: Can't you just fill `v` directly instead of using a temporary?

Comment: That depends: do you need to copy or swap?

Comment: @netcoder: That wouldn't be exception-safe.

Comment: Does your compiler support move semantics?  `std::move` would work great if `w` truly is "temporary".

Comment: @Chad: `w` in `v = w;` is not an rvalue, so the move optimization can't be inserted here automatically.  You are right that you can force it with `std::move(w)` (which is why I put that in my answer just a couple seconds before your comment).

Comment: @BenVoigt: In this short example, it wouldn't, you're right.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you should swap here.  In C++11, you can also say `v = std::move(w);`.

Either way, the variable `w` is going out of scope immediately, so its contents don't matter, and you might as well transfer ownership instead of copying.

Comment: With C++11, are there situations when we prefer swap over move

Comment: @ATemp: When you need to *swap* rather than *move*? That is, when you just want to interchange the state of the objects (none of those objects is going out of scope directly).